# Merge list of tuples

Tags: python

What's the pythonic way of achieving the following?

from:

```
l1 = ([('ADJ', 29), ('CONJ', 1), ('PRT', 2), ('X', 3), ('ADV', 18), ('VERB', 52), ('ADP', 1), ('NOUN', 27)])
l2 = ([('ADJ', 312), ('INTJ', 2), ('ADP', 5), ('PART', 6), ('DET', 2), ('ADV', 323), ('VERB', 1196), ('NOUN', 1162)])
```

to:

```
l3 = ([('ADJ', 312,29), ('ADP', 5,1), ('ADV', 323,18), ('VERB', 1196,52), ('NOUN', 1162,27)])
```

Comment: Show your attempt and it's spelt 'tuples'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
l1 = ([('ADJ', 29), ('CONJ', 1), ('PRT', 2), ('X', 3), ('ADV', 18), ('VERB', 52), ('ADP', 1), ('NOUN', 27)])
l2 = ([('ADJ', 312), ('INTJ', 2), ('ADP', 5), ('PART', 6), ('DET', 2), ('ADV', 323), ('VERB', 1196), ('NOUN', 1162)])
d1 = dict(l1)
d2 = dict(l2)
new_data = tuple([(c, d1[c], d2.get(c, None)) for c in d1])    
final_data = list(filter(lambda x:len(x) > 2, tuple(map(tuple, tuple([(b for b in i if b is not None) for i in new_data])))))
```

Output:

```
[('ADV', 18, 323), ('NOUN', 27, 1162), ('ADP', 1, 5), ('VERB', 52, 1196), ('ADJ', 29, 312)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean you could do:

`result = [(a, b, d) for (a, b), (c, d) in zip(l1, l2)]`

I believe that will do what you're asking (but I can't test it right now)

Comment: Scratch that, I just noticed that your lists don't have the same elements

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure python has a one liner for this but what you could do is merge the two lists using a dictionary.

```
l1 = ([('ADJ', 29), ('CONJ', 1), ('PRT', 2), ('X', 3), ('ADV', 18), ('VERB', 52), ('ADP', 1), ('NOUN', 27)])
l2 = ([('ADJ', 312), ('INTJ', 2), ('ADP', 5), ('PART', 6), ('DET', 2), ('ADV', 323), ('VERB', 1196), ('NOUN', 1162)])
d2 = dict(l2)

#Merge l1 and d2
result = [(k, v, d2[k]) for k, v in l1]
```